Cached location of annotationProcessor library
For legacy and resource availability reasons, I'm building our Android app with an old version of a database wrapper (DBFlow 3.1.1). Recently this library version vanished from Maven, and I can't find it on any other public-facing repos. I know it's hugely out-of-date, but for now, I can't upgrade to more recent versions, nor port over to Room easily.
implementation 'com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:3.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:3.1.1'

I can still build the app in Android Studio locally as it's calling on cached versions of these libraries on my Mac. However, if I try to build on a different computer, or one of my colleagues pulls from BitBucket to do some work, these libraries are no longer available and the build fails.
I can find the cached .JAR files for the two 'implementation' libraries, and add these to the gradle build scripts and that part of the build works.
But I cannot find where the annotationProcessor library cache is. Does such a thing exist? If yes, where can I grab it from, and how can I add that cache into the gradle build scripts?

Aside, but can you clarify on "vanished from Maven" - maven central doesn't support removing versions after they've been published...

The oldest version of DBFlow on Maven appears to be 4.0.x or similar. Or at least I can't find the version I need.

It looks like it was distributed on jitpack. fwiw, the dependencies should be cached locally at ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1.

Thanx @BenManes - found the files I need. Sadly adding these to the libs folder just kicks up a host of different errors that aren't obvious how to resolve, but that's another question...
And building a new project that only imports v3.1.1 from jitpack fails too. C'est la vie.
